# How to create a dynamic jQuery string of checkbox id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Im at my wits end with this one.

When i click a checkbox, I want add the ID of the checkbox to a comma separated string in an input below. I have this working however, what I can not do is remove the ID and its comma if it already exists in the input field (checking and unchecking).

Simple form.

```
<form>
<input class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1" name="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<input  class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2" name="<?php echo $title; ?>">
<input  class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="3" id="3" name="<?php echo $title; ?>">

<!-- Note that this field may or may not have an existing string of ID's (1,2,3) from previous saves -->    
<input type="text" id="excludelist" value="<?php echo $saved-string; ?>">
</form>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.iteminput').on('click', function(){
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('ID');
        var string = jQuery('#excludelist').val();
        var newstring = string + id + ',';
        jQuery('#excludelist').val(newstring);
    })
})
```

Comment: _"what I can not do is remove the ID and its comma if it already exists in the input field"_ Can you include `javascript` at Question where you tried removing the string from `input` `.value`? Why do you concatenate the string if you can check if the string is already present within the `.value` before concatenating the string?

Comment: Seems like the easiest approach to this would be just to rebuild the entire comma selected list any time a checkbox state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the input box, and use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the string of IDs into an array. At that point you can check if the ID you are looking for is in that array. Example:

```
const id = 3;
const inputValue = $('input[type=text]').val();

// Split the IDs into an array by comma.
const currentIds = inputValue.split(',');

if (currentIds.indexOf(id) === -1) {
    // ID has not yet been added to the input box.
    // We can add it to the array here, and
    // update it later.
    currentIds.push(id);
} else {
    // ID is in the current list of IDs. We
    // can remove it like this:
    currentIds.splice(currentIds.indexOf(id), 1);
}

// Finally, we can reset the input string
// with the new values we set above.
$('input[type=text]').val(currentIds.join(','));
```

See:

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Could you expand your code please and explain how you add and remove the ID from the input field?

Comment: You can add/remove the IDs from the array as needed, then use JavaScript's `Array.prototype.join()` method to recreate the string and set that as the value. I'll update my answer to give you a better example.

Comment: Updated with a more complete example

Comment: Ok, looks like this is working although - The first id shows a , before it (,1 or ,2 or ,3) Im not sure that will pass in my PHP.
All I have to do now is to mark all the checkboxes in that string as checked.

Comment: You can easily remove the leading comma with the substring method

Answer (score 1):

Why not just rebuild it?

```js
var $iteminputs = $('.iteminput');

$iteminputs.on('change', function(){
  var ids = $.map($iteminputs.filter(':checked'), function(element){ return element.id; });
  $('#excludelist').val(ids.join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="1" id="1" name="title1">
<input  class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="2" id="2" name="title2" checked>
<input  class="iteminput" type="checkbox" value="3" id="3" name="title3" checked>

<!-- Note that this field may or may not have an existing string of ID's (1,2,3) from previous saves -->    
<input type="text" id="excludelist" value="2,3">
```